# How to solve $(2x+1)y' = 4x + 2y$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to solve $(2x+1)y' = 4x + 2y$

Well, I'm supposed to solve with seperate/homogenous/linear differential system this question, and I can't use any of them. Can anyone give me a hint please?

Linear differential system:

[image]

How can I solve $\int \frac{4x}{2x+1}e^{ln(2x+1)}dx$

Comment: It is linear; divide by $2x+1$ to get it in *standard form*.

Comment: @StackTD I see that now, but how can I approach the integral $\int b(x)e^A(x) dx$ when $b(x) = \frac{4x}{2x+1}$?

Comment: Write it as $y'+p(x)y=q(x)$then multiply by $exp(\int p(x)dx)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noted in the question, $A(x)=\int \frac{-2}{2x+1}=-\ln|2x+1|$

$\int \frac{4x}{2x+1}e^{-\ln|2x+1|}dx$

but notice $e^{-\ln|2x+1|}=\frac{1}{|2x+1|}$.

So $\int \frac{4x}{2x+1}e^{-\ln|2x+1|}dx=\int \frac{4x}{(2x+1)^2}$ (if $x>-\frac{1}{2}$). You can integrate this using substitution. Note that $x=-\frac{1}{2}$ is a singularity.

Answer (score 1):

Notice, for the general formula:

$$\text{a}\left(x\right)\cdot\text{y}'\left(x\right)+\text{b}\left(x\right)\cdot\text{y}\left(x\right)=\text{c}\left(x\right)\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\text{y}'\left(x\right)+\frac{\text{b}\left(x\right)\cdot\text{y}\left(x\right)}{\text{a}\left(x\right)}=\frac{\text{c}\left(x\right)}{\text{a}\left(x\right)}\Longleftrightarrow$$

---

Let $\text{r}\left(x\right)=\exp\left(\int\frac{\text{b}\left(x\right)}{\text{a}\left(x\right)}\space\text{d}x\right)$.

Multiply both sides by $\text{r}\left(x\right)$:

---

$$\text{r}\left(x\right)\cdot\text{y}'\left(x\right)+\text{r}\left(x\right)\cdot\frac{\text{b}\left(x\right)\cdot\text{y}\left(x\right)}{\text{a}\left(x\right)}=\text{r}\left(x\right)\cdot\frac{\text{c}\left(x\right)}{\text{a}\left(x\right)}\Longleftrightarrow$$

---

Substitute:

$$\frac{\text{d}\text{r}\left(x\right)}{\text{d}x}=\text{r}'\left(x\right)=\text{r}\left(x\right)\cdot\frac{\text{b}\left(x\right)}{\text{a}\left(x\right)}$$

---

$$\text{r}\left(x\right)\cdot\text{y}'\left(x\right)+\text{r}'\left(x\right)\cdot\text{y}\left(x\right)=\text{r}\left(x\right)\cdot\frac{\text{c}\left(x\right)}{\text{a}\left(x\right)}\Longleftrightarrow$$

---

Apply the reverse product rule:

---

$$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(\text{r}\left(x\right)\cdot\text{y}\left(x\right)\right)=\text{r}\left(x\right)\cdot\frac{\text{c}\left(x\right)}{\text{a}\left(x\right)}\Longleftrightarrow$$

---

Integrate both sides with respect to $x$:

---

$$\int\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(\text{r}\left(x\right)\cdot\text{y}\left(x\right)\right)\space\text{d}x=\int\text{r}\left(x\right)\cdot\frac{\text{c}\left(x\right)}{\text{a}\left(x\right)}\space\text{d}x\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\text{r}\left(x\right)\cdot\text{y}\left(x\right)=\text{K}+\int\text{r}\left(x\right)\cdot\frac{\text{c}\left(x\right)}{\text{a}\left(x\right)}\space\text{d}x\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\text{y}\left(x\right)=\frac{1}{\text{r}\left(x\right)}\cdot\left\{\text{K}+\int\text{r}\left(x\right)\cdot\frac{\text{c}\left(x\right)}{\text{a}\left(x\right)}\space\text{d}x\right\}$$

So:

$$\color{red}{\text{y}\left(x\right)=\exp\left(-\int\frac{\text{b}\left(x\right)}{\text{a}\left(x\right)}\space\text{d}x\right)\cdot\left\{\text{K}+\int\exp\left(\int\frac{\text{b}\left(x\right)}{\text{a}\left(x\right)}\space\text{d}x\right)\cdot\frac{\text{c}\left(x\right)}{\text{a}\left(x\right)}\space\text{d}x\right\}}$$

Where $\text{K}$ is an arbitrary constant.

Comment: How long exactly did it take you to write all that out?

Comment: @SkeletonBow Not that much time. Why are you asking?

Comment: Seems like it took you at least 20 minutes or something. Did it take you less? Did you use a program or did you just write it out by hand? I'd love to know if I could type equations faster somehow.

Comment: @SkeletonBow I did it in round about 10 minutes. But when you want to become faster answering questions, just practice a lot. I must say that the answer already was given when I posted my answer, but I did that to show how you can solve these kinds of problems in a more general way.

Comment: I see. Thank you for the suggestion! :)

Comment: @SkeletonBow You're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Well, in case you're wondering how to do $\int\frac{4x}{2x+1}e^{\color{red}{\frac{1}{2}}\ln(2x+1)}\,dx$,

Use the substitution $u=2x+1$.

Now,

$$\begin{align*}
e^{\frac{1}{2}\ln(2x+1)} &= e^{\ln(\sqrt{2x+1})} \\
&= \sqrt{2x+1} \\
\end{align*}$$

So

$$\begin{align*}
\int \frac{4x}{2x+1} \sqrt{2x+1} \,\mathrm{d}x &= \int \frac{4x}{\sqrt{2x+1}} \,\mathrm{d}x \\
&= \int \frac{2 \left( \frac{u-1}{2} \right)}{\sqrt{u}} \,\mathrm{d}u \\
&= \int \frac{u-1}{\sqrt{u}} \,\mathrm{d}u \\
&= \int u^{1/2} - u^{-1/2} \,\mathrm{d}u \\
&= \frac{2}{3}u^{3/2} - 2u^{\frac{1}{2}} + c \\
&= \frac{2}{3}(2x+1)^{3/2} - 2 \sqrt{2x+1} + c \\
\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite in the form of a first order linear ODE:$\quad \:y'\left(x\right)+p\left(x\right)\cdot y=q\left(x\right)$
$$p\left(x\right)=-\frac{2}{2x+1},\:\quad q\left(x\right)=\frac{4x}{2x+1}$$